# Horizontal scrolling between dynamic number of pages with tabs in Polymer

Tags: polymer

Is there a Polymer WebComponent that allows horizontal scrolling between dynamic number of pages with tabs?

To those familiar with Android im looking for something like [PagerTabStrip](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [swipe-pages](https://github.com/TheSeamau5/swipe-pages) custom element allows horizontal scrolling with tabs. You can check the demo here: http://theseamau5.github.io/swipe-pages/components/swipe-pages/demo.html.
But this has not been updated for a long time.